# Is it ok to return CompletedTask from BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have the following two alternatives:

```cs
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
     _ = ForeverRunningLoop(stoppingToken);

     return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private Task ForeverRunningLoop(CancellationToken token)
{
     while(true)
     {
          token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          // Do some asynchronous work...
     }
}
```

```cs
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
     await ForeverRunningLoop(stoppingToken);
}

private Task ForeverRunningLoop(CancellationToken token)
{
     while(true)
     {
          token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          // Do some asynchronous work...
     }
}
```

Is there any difference between those? If so, which one is better?

Comment: The third - `return ForeverRunningLoop(stoppingToken);` In fact, if that's the only code in `ExecuteAsync` why have a separate `ForeverRunningLoop` ? Why not put that code inside `ExecuteAsync` ?

Comment: It's a simplified example, I wanted to have idea if there's any difference between returning a completed task vs returning an ongoing task.

Comment: The question was a bit oversimplified. There's no benefit to the first snippet. Whether you need to use `await` or directly return the task depends on what else is going on in the function. If the call to the loop is the last one, you can return the task returned by `ForeverRunningLoop` directly and avoid generating the state machine used by `async/await`. That's not a huge benefit though as `ExecuteAsync` is only called once per service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific scenario, the `Task` returned from `ExecuteAsync` is ignored, so there's no behavioral difference between the two.

I would still recommend the second option (or just merge the methods completely as suggested in the comments), because it *looks* wrong to do a fire-and-forget discard like that. Code like the first option is a major red flag in literally any scenario other than `ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: Right, I think the second approach has a benefit of including ExecuteAsync in the stack trace in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

They will behave the same, only in rare cases when Task returned from  `ForeverRunningLoop` fails before returning the results, the second one will bubble up the exception.

[BackgroundService source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs)

```
public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Create linked token to allow cancelling executing task from provided token
            _stoppingCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

            // Store the task we're executing
            _executeTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

            // If the task is completed then return it, this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
            if (_executeTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                return _executeTask;
            }

            // Otherwise it's running
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```